# Quais são os delimitadores válidos para expressões regulares preg_?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Quais são os delimitadores válidos para expressões regulares nas [funções `preg_*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php)?

Sei que podemos utilizar algumas dessas (`/`, `~` e `#`), como mostro no exemplo abaixo:

```
$numero = '0.12.13';
preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $numero); // string('01213')
preg_replace('~\D+~', '', $numero); // string('01213')
preg_replace('#\D+#', '', $numero); // string('01213')
```

Mas gostaria de saber quais são os outros delimitadores de expressões regulares (da `PREG`) no PHP.

Posso usar apenas caracteres especiais (e nunca números ou letras)?

Se sim, quais são esses caracteres especiais?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.delimiters.php:

> A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.

(tradução livre)

Um delimitador pode ser qualquer caractere não alfanumérico, não barra invertida, não espaço em branco.

Os que você usou no exemplo são os mais comuns. São muitas opções de delimitadores válidos (inclusive os que tem função especial na expressão regular): `.`, `$`, `_`, `:`, `?`, `^`, `%`, `&`

Demonstração: https://ideone.com/uhTzHe

Comment: Apenas acrescentando, de preferencia não se usa o caracteres reservados da linguagem, pois caso você necessite usá-los sera necessário esquipá-los com o `\\`. Eu por exemplo sempre uso `~` pois  não é reservado da linguagem.

Answer (score 2):

Apenas complementando a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83064/112052), se você usar os caracteres `{`, `(`, `[` ou `<` no início, o delimitador final não pode ser o mesmo caractere:

```
preg_replace('{\D+{', '', $numero); // erro: No ending matching delimiter
                  ^ aqui não pode usar o mesmo caractere ("{")
```

Neste caso, você deve encerrar a expressão com o respectivo caractere de fechamento (ou seja, `}`, `)`, `]` ou `>`):

```
$numero = '0.12.13';
echo preg_replace('{\D+}', '', $numero); // 01213
echo preg_replace('(\D+)', '', $numero); // 01213
echo preg_replace('[\D+]', '', $numero); // 01213
echo preg_replace('<\D+>', '', $numero); // 01213
```

Para os demais [caracteres permitidos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), você usa sempre o mesmo no início e fim da expressão.

---

Só para constar que o uso de outros delimitadores é útil para evitar muitos escapes dentro da expressão. Por exemplo, se eu usar as barras como delimitadores, dentro da regex as barras devem ser escapadas:

```
$numero = '0/1/2.1/3';
// eliminar somente as barras
echo preg_replace('/\//', '', $numero); // 012.13
```

Repare que eu tive que escrever a barra como `\/`, para que ela fosse considerada parte da regex e não fosse confundida com o delimitador.

Mas eu poderia evitar este escape mudando os delimitadores:

```
echo preg_replace('#/#', '', $numero); // 012.13
```

Neste caso o ganho não foi *tão* grande assim, mas se a expressão tivesse muitas vezes o caractere `/`, isso poderia diminuir a "chateação" de ficar escrevendo `\/` toda hora (além de deixar a regex - na minha opinião - um pouco mais legível).

---

Outro ponto - que pode ser meio confuso - é que se eu usar como delimitador um dos *brackets* que possuem significado especial em regex (`{`, `[` ou `(`), dentro da expressão eles não precisam ser escapados:

```
// remover sequência de 3 ou mais números seguida de barra
echo preg_replace('{\d{3,}/}', '', '123/245.144/3'); // 245.3

// remover os dígitos 2 ou 4 e o outro dígito que tiver depois
echo preg_replace('[[2-4]\d]', '', '12.23-45/14'); // 12.-/14

// remover somente os dígitos 2 ou 4, desde que não tenha um dígito antes
echo preg_replace('((?<=\D)[2-4])', '', '12.23-45/14'); // 12.3-5/14
```

Repare que mesmo usando `{`, `[` ou `(` como delimitadores, dentro da regex estes caracteres podem ser usados normalmente.

Comment: Realmente vejam como isso sobre [], <>, {}, () pode atrapalhar (confundir), funciona `preg_replace('#[{]#', 'foo', '{ { {')` já assim irá falhar `preg_replace('{[{]}', 'foo', '{ { {')` (No ending matching delimiter '}' found), o que vai acabar exigindo "escapar" o { dentro do [...], assim `'{[\{]}'`. Em uma regex simples, será fácil de resolver, em uma mais complexa dará mais dores de cabeça.