# Como utilizar preg_match_all neste trecho?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
<div>
  <span class="dark_text">Type:</span>
  <a href="https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?type=var1">var2</a></div>~
```

Eu preciso usar `preg_match_all` para encontrar a variável `var2` independentemente o que esteja escrito na `var 1`.

Exemplo:

```
preg_match_all('!<a href="https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?type=var1">(.*?)</a></div>',$result,$match);
```

Comment: Olá Diogo, podes traduzir a pergunta para Português?

Comment: preciso de fazer preg match all a variavel var2 independentemente o que esteja escrito na var 1

Comment: Olá Diogo, use o [EDITAR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/209984/edit)  para traduzir sua pergunta, esse é o Stackoverflow em Português. Irá facilitar para as pessoas te ajudarem.

Answer (score 1):

**Essa resposta se baseia na pergunta [antes da edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/209984/3).**

Basta que utilize:

```
/<a href="https:\/\/myanimelist.net\/topanime.php\?type=var1">(.*?)<\/a><\/div>/
```

É necessário que escape a `/` e o `?`, caso contrário não irá funcionar. Assim ele irá obter o `(.*?)` que está entre a string.

```
preg_match_all('/<a href="https:\/\/myanimelist.net\/topanime.php\?type=var1">(.*?)<\/a><\/div>/',$result,$match);


var_dump($match);
```

Resultado:

```
array(2) {
  [0]
  array(1) {
    [0]
    string(71) "<a href="https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?type=var1">var2</a>"
  }
  [1]
  array(1) {
    [0]
    string(4) "var2"
  }
}
```

*Também considere procurar por [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php), assim poderá encontrar outras opções.*

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro detalhe é que em PHP as regex [devem ter delimitadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83063/112052) (um caractere que indica o início e fim da expressão). No seu caso, você usou `!`, então faltou colocar outro `!` no final.

Além disso, vários caracteres possuem significado especial em regex, como o ponto e o `?` (a interrogação indica que algo é [opcional](https://regular-expressions.info/optional.html), então no seu caso o trecho `php?` signfica "ph" seguido de um "p" opcional). Se quer que eles sejam considerados caracteres comuns, sem significado especial, deve-se fazer o escape com `\`. Então ficaria:

```
$texto = '<div>
<span class="dark_text">Type:</span>
<a href="https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?type=var1">var2</a></div>';
if (preg_match_all('!<a href="https://myanimelist\.net/topanime\.php\?type=var1">(.*?)</a></div>!', $texto, $match)) {
    var_dump($match);
}
```

Se quer pegar somente o conteúdo que está dentro da tag `a` (ou seja, `var2`), basta pegar `$match[1]`.

---

## Não use regex

Mas na verdade [regex não é a ferramenta ideal para manipular HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052) (saiba mais lendo [esta famosa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)).

Neste caso, seria melhor usar [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument):

```
$texto = '<div>
<span class="dark_text">Type:</span>
<a href="https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?type=var1">var2</a></div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($texto);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//a[@href="https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?type=var1"]') as $link) { // procura elementos a com a URL desejada
    echo $link->textContent; // var2
}
```

Por mais que "funcione" em casos mais simples, a regex pode falhar conforme o HTML fica mais complexo (por exemplo, se o link estiver comentado, a regex não detecta, já `DOMDocument` consegue detectar e ignorar os trechos comentados, etc). [Regex nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

---

Conforme indicado nos comentários, se `var1` é variável na URL, uma alternativa é alterar para:

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//a[starts-with(@href, "https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?type=")]') as $link) { // procura elementos a com a URL desejada
    parse_str(parse_url($link->getAttribute('href'), PHP_URL_QUERY), $output);
    if ($output['type'] == 'var1') { // se type é "var1" (ou qualquer outro valor que você quiser) 
        echo $link->textContent; // var2
    }
}
```

Comment: A ideia do DOM eu concordo, regex pode até atender, mas é melhor o nativo que é pronto para o foco especifico, ainda sim creio que o uso de XPath nisto até foi bom, mas poderia ser ajustado para tratar de outra forma, pq a intenção do autor é que o tal var1 na verdade seja dinâmico, poderia simplesmente usar [`getElementsByTagName('a')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) e no iterar do for pegar os links e usar `parse_str(parse_url($link, PHP_URL_QUERY), $output); var_dump($output);` ....

Comment: ... mas é apenas sugestão, dá pra resolver parte no proprio xpath, mas ao invés de `[@href=...]` usaria o `[starts-with(@href, "https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?type=")]`, ou então acaso o link tenha querystrings dinamicas usaria uma combinação `[starts-with(@href, "https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?") and contains(@href, "type=")]` e depois pegar com o parse_url+parse_str

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Atualizei a resposta (eu tinha entendido errado, achei que o "var1" era fixo), obrigado pelas sugestões!