# Formatar uma duração "hora:minuto" para o formato ISO 8601

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Estou tentando transformar a string `05:25` para `PT05M25S`.

Consegui chegar até aqui, altera o `:` pelo `M`. Mas não consegui inserir o restante que ficou faltando.

```
$date = "05:25";

$date = preg_replace('/[:\/]/', 'M', $date);

echo $date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiz desse jeito:

```
$duration   = 05:25;

$duration   = preg_replace('/[:\/]/', 'M', $duration);

echo 'PT' . $duration . 'S';
```

Resultado: `PT05M25S`

Answer (score 1):

O problema com seu código é que as barras no início e fim são delimitadores da regex. Por isso, quando uma outra barra é encontrada no meio da expressão, o PHP acha que a regex já terminou e dá erro. Uma forma de resolver é [a que você fez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/435958/112052): escapar a barra com `\`.

Outra opção é usar um caractere diferente como delimitador, já que [há vários outros caracteres que podem ser usados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83063/112052) além da barra. De preferência, escolha um que não está sendo usado na regex, assim você não precisa se preocupar com o escape:

```
// usando # como delimitador
$duration = preg_replace('#[:/]#', 'M', $duration);
```

Mas neste caso, não sei se precisa de regex, afinal você só quer trocar o caractere `:` por `M`, então um simples [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) já resolveria:

```
$duration = "05:25";
echo "PT". str_replace(':', 'M', $duration). "S";
```

---

Mas como você está trabalhando com durações (quantidades de tempo), talvez seja interessante usar um [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval):

```
$duration = "05:25";
$partes = explode(':', $duration);
$d = DateInterval::createFromDateString("{$partes[0]} minutes + {$partes[1]} seconds");
$formatado = "PT";
if ($d->i > 0) {
    $formatado .= "{$d->i}M";
}
if ($d->s > 0) {
    $formatado .= "{$d->s}S";
}

echo $formatado; // PT5M25S
```

Pode parecer "pior" só porque o código ficou maior, mas creio que fica um pouco mais robusto, pois se a string não tiver números (por exemplo, se for `"ab:xy"`), ocorrerá um erro ao criar o `DateInterval`. Neste caso, bastaria verificar se ele foi criado mesmo:

```
$duration = "ab:xy"; // string inválida
$partes = explode(':', $duration);
$d = DateInterval::createFromDateString("{$partes[0]} minutes + {$partes[1]} seconds");
if ($d) {
    // $d foi criado corretamente, formatar o valor usando o código acima
} else {
    echo "erro ao criar o intervalo";
}
```

Já usando *replace*, não é feita nenhuma verificação, e ele aceita qualquer string que vier.

Eu incluí uma verificação para não colocar o valor na string quando este for zero, então se a string for `"00:25"` o resultado será `PT25S`. A [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) (que define este formato para durações) diz que não há problema em ter valores zerados, mas que estes podem ser omitidos caso sejam zero. Fica a seu critério decidir se vai incluir ou não.

---

Obviamente dá para melhorar, pois eu não verifiquei se o array retornado por `explode` possui duas posições, etc. Também não está claro se o formato sempre é "minutos:segundos". Se for, outra opção é [usar `format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php):

```
$duration = "05:25";
$partes = explode(':', $duration);
$d = DateInterval::createFromDateString("{$partes[0]} minutes + {$partes[1]} seconds");
echo $d->format('PT%iM%sS'); // PT5M25S
```

A diferença para o código anterior é que mesmo quando os valores forem zero eles serão incluídos na string. Por exemplo, para `"00:25"` o resultado será `PT0M25S`.