# Problema com regex em php

Tags: php, regex

Olá, no meu código eu quero separar uma string, tendo como separador um valor que deveria ser encontrado via expressão regular.
Abaixo o que tentei:

```
    $data = "Amazing.Stories.2020.S01E03.REPACK.720p.WEB.H264-GHOSTS.mkv";

    $pattern = "[#^S\d\dE\d\d$#i]";
    $d = preg_split($pattern, $data);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($d);
    echo "</pre>";
```

No caso o separador deveria ser "S01E03", mas não está conseguindo encontrar. o resultado que está dando é :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Amazing.Stories.2020.S01E03.REPACK.720p.WEB.H264-GHOSTS.mkv
)
```

O resultado desejavel seria:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Amazing.Stories.2020
   [1] => REPACK.720p.WEB.H264-GHOSTS.mkv
)
```

Confesso que sou ruim com expressões regulares, mas esta mesma pattern encontra quando eu a uso em um preg_grep por exemplo.

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Reverti a edição porque ao mudar a pergunta vc acaba invalidando a resposta, e a ideia do site é ter uma pergunta por problema específico. Se tem outra dúvida (mesmo que esteja relacionada), por favor [faça outra pergunta](/questions/ask) (não esquecendo de pesquisar antes se já não existe algo no site, claro)

Comment: E caso a resposta abaixo tenha resolvido a questão do split, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema.

Comment: obrigado novamente @hkotsubo. Foi de grande valia a sua resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude a regex para:

```
$pattern = '#\.S\d{2}E\d{2}\.#i';
```

Os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` indicam respectivamente o início e final da string, então não faz sentido usar isso em um *split*, já que o padrão estará no meio do texto. Remova-os.

Também retirei os colchetes, que neste caso estavam sendo usados como [delimitadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/432729/112052) da expressão - ou seja, o `#` também fazia parte da regex. Deixando assim, o `#` passa a ser o delimitador.

Também mudei os dois dígitos para `\d{2}` (dá na mesma usar `\d\d`), e incluí os pontos antes e depois do texto, pois entendi que eles não fazem parte do resultado. Lembrando que o ponto possui significado especial em regex (significa ["qualquer caractere, exceto quebras de linha"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)), então para que ele seja interpretado apenas como o caractere `.`, preciso escapá-lo com `\`.

A [*flag* `i`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) indica que a regex é *case insensitive*, ou seja, também vai considerar as letras "s" e "e" minúsculas. Se só quiser considerar as maiúsculas, retire o `i` do final da expressão.

Comment: obrigado, vou testar

Comment: como eu obtive com sua ajuda a parte anterior e posterior do encontrado pelo regex, eu peguei o S00E00 simplesmente utilizando str_replace.